# Getting RNetLogo to work on El Capitan

Tags: java, r, netlogo

I'm having the same error as others in trying to get RNetLogo to run in OSX:

```
>     NLStart(nl.path)
>     Error in .jnew("nlcon/Preprocess") : 
>       java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: nlcon/Preprocess : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I've been through all the fixes I can find incluing
http://codegur.com/26745364/getting-r-to-use-newer-versions-of-java
https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/37

But still no joy. According to this:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RNetLogo/news.html
the problem has been fixed. I'm using the latest version of R, RNetLogo and NetLogo 5.2.1.

Has anyone got any advice?